# two tables query with same primary key

Tags: mysql

I have two tables with same primary key name "codigo",
[image: First table]
[image: Second table]

I try to make a mysql query to combine both results on new one table.
[image: result table]

```
SELECT * FROM recuperacion.inventario, recuperacion.Salidas where codigo='5ae2399f4fbd3';
```

this query is not work.

Comment: ever heard of JOINS?

Comment: Your query creates [Cartesian Product](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-cartesian-joins.htm) of the two tables and then applies your filter. I do not think you wanted that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join the tables.

```
SELECT *
FROM recuperacion.inventario
INNER JOIN recuperacion.Salidas USING (codigo)
WHERE codigo='5ae2399f4fbd3';
```

The `USING` clause can be used when the joining relationship is the same column name(s) in both tables. This then allows you to refer to that column without qualifying it with a table prefix.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
-- INTO NewTableName
FROM recuperacion.inventario t1
INNER JOIN recuperacion.Salidas t2  
  ON t1.codigo = t2.codigo
WHERE t1.codigo='5ae2399f4fbd3'
```

NOTE:  this will get you all columns from both tables.  If you only want specific columns you need to edit the select list.  Just be sure to use the aliases.

Answer (score 0):

Use a JOIN syntax for the query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM recuperacion.inventario a JOIN recuperacion.Salidas b 
ON a.codigo = b.codigo
WHERE a.codigo='5ae2399f4fbd3';
```

Comment: You need to qualify the column name in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I missed putting that. Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use join

```
SELECT * 
FROM recuperacion.inventario tab1
INNER JOIN recuperacion.Salidas  tab2
on tab1.codigo = tab2.codigo
where tab1.codigo='5ae2399f4fbd3'
```